# ¿Cómo mostrar los datos de una función creada en SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

He creado esta función y le he dado el respectivo execute.
¿Cómo hago para ver el resultado de la función?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: se supone que con el select te retorna el resultado, un decimal

Answer (score 0):

Para regresar el valor de una función escalar, solo hay que usarla como un valor escalar y poner sus parámetros entre paréntesis.

```
SELECT TOTAL_VENTAS( @SRV_ID) AS Total_Ventas
```

o

```
SELECT TOTAL_VENTAS( ut.SRV_ID) AS Total_Ventas,
       *
FROM UnaTabla ut
```